# Jquery div slideshow not working in Safari (works in Chrome, FF.)

Tags: jquery, html, safari

I have a simple div fading slider that works in Chrome, Firefox, and on my iPad but won't fire in a Safari browser. The next/back anchors are not firing the function. They're not even showing the little finger on hover. Has anyone had this problem or know a possible solution?

```
window.onload = function () {
$(".divs div").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
        $(this).hide();
});

$("#next").click(function(){
    if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
        $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).next().fadeIn();
        });
    else {
        $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut(function(){
            $(".divs div:first").fadeIn();
        });
    }
    return false;
});

$("#prev").click(function(){
    if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
        $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).prev().fadeIn();
        });
    else {
        $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut(function(){
            $(".divs div:last").fadeIn();
        });
    }
    return false;
});
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="divs">

<div class="cls1">..image/text..</div>
<div class="cls2">..image/text..</div>
<div class="cls3">..image/text..</div>
...

</div>

<a id="prev" href="#"></a>
<a id="next" href="#"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your script on Safari and it works for me. Maybe you should try linting your script. Even if it doesn't solve the problem, it will certainly avoid broken scripts in the future:

```
$(".divs div").each(function (e) {
    if (e !== 0) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});

$("#next").click(function () {

    if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length !== 0) {
        $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut(function () {
            $(this).next().fadeIn();
        });
    } else {
        $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut(function () {
            $(".divs div:first").fadeIn();
        });
    }
    return false;
});

$("#prev").click(function () {

    if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length !== 0) {
        $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut(function () {
            $(this).prev().fadeIn();
        });
    } else {
        $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut(function () {
            $(".divs div:last").fadeIn();
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/624wu49h/

Comment: It turned out to be a CSS issue. In Safari the wrap around the images/text was blocking the anchors. Relative positioning and z-index fixed it. Thanks for the quick response though. Appreciate it.